# Collapsing a large dataset while conditionally preserving some missing values

Tags: sas, data-cleaning

Dataset `HAVE` includes `id` values and a character variable of `names`. Values in `names` are usually missing. If `names` is missing for all values of an `id` EXCEPT one, the obs for IDs with missing values in `names` can be deleted. If `names` is completely missing for all `id` of a certain value (like `id` = 2 or 5 below), one record for this `id` value must be preserved.

In other words, I need to turn `HAVE`:

```
id  names
1
1
1   Matt, Lisa, Dan
1
2
2
2
3
3
3   Emily, Nate
3
4
4
4   Bob
5
```

into `WANT`:

```
id  names
1   Matt, Lisa, Dan
2
3   Emily, Nate
4   Bob
5
```

I currently do this by deleting all records where `names` is missing, then merging the results onto a new dataset `KEY` with one variable `id` that contains all original values (1, 2, 3, 4, and 5):

```
data WANT_pre;
set HAVE;
if names = " " then delete;
run;

data WANT;
merge KEY
      WANT_pre;
   by id;
run;
```

This is ideal for `HAVE` because I know that `id` is a set of numeric values ranging from 1 to 5. But I am less sure how I could do this efficiently (A) on a much larger file, and (B) if if I couldn't simply create an id `KEY` dataset by counting from 1 to n. If your `HAVE` had a few million observations and your `id` values were more complex (e.g., hexadecimal values like XR4GN), how would you produce `WANT`?

Comment: Do you ever have different values for  `names` in different rows with the same  `id`? If so, which `names` would you keep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQL here easily, MAX() applies to character variables within SQL.

```
proc sql; 
create table want as
select id, max(names) as names
from have
group by ID;
quit;
```

Another option is to use an UPDATE statement instead.

```
data want;
update have (obs=0) have;
by ID;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good candidate for a DOW-loop, assuming that your dataset is sorted by `id`:

```
data want;
do until(last.id);
  set have;
  by id;
  length t_names $50; /*Set this to at least the same length as names unless you want the default length of 200 from coalescec*/ 
  t_names = coalescec(t_names,names);
end;
names = t_names;
drop t_names;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
proc summary data=have nway missing;
   class id;
   output out=want(drop=_:) idgroup(max(names) out(names)=);
   run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `UPDATE` statement.  That will ignore the missing values and keep the last non-missing value.  It normally requires a master and transaction dataset, but you can use your single dataset for both.

```
data want;
  update have(obs=0) have ;
  by id;
run;
```